# Converting a DB2 SQL Query with bitwise AND to a SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2

The company I work for uses a program called Showcase to build reports in our finance departmet, Showcase builds the SQL Query based on criteria inserted into the interface and returns the data which is then used in Excel for further formatting and analysis.  We have one particular report that keeps breaking, so I am trying to rewrite the Query in SQL Server.

There is a part in the FROM Clause that performs a bitwise AND. I have never utilized this before in a SQL Query and this is where the Query has its issue. I'm not even sure what is it trying to achieve with the bitwise AND - is it just a more accurate method of comparing two values?

Here is the FROM Clause as it is coming straight of Showcase:

```
FROM 
S06947A4.GLDBFA.GLPCT T01 
INNER JOIN S06947A4.GLDBFA.GLPDA GLPDA ON  T01.CTCO=GLPDA.DACO  
LEFT OUTER JOIN S06947A4.GLDBFA.GLPBX T02 ON  T01.CTCO=T02.BXCO  AND T01.CTPAGE=T02.BXPAGE  AND GLPDA.DAYEAR=T02.BXYEAR  AND &GLMORS=T02.BXMORS  
LEFT OUTER JOIN S06947A4.GLDBFA.GLPGL T03 ON  T01.CTCO=T03.GLCO  AND T01.CTPAGE=T03.GLPAGE  AND GLPDA.DAYEAR=T03.GLYEAR  AND &GLMORS=T03.GLMORS
```

The issue seems to be with the last part of the two LEFT OUTER JOINS:

```
&GLMORS=T02.BXMORS
&GLMORS=T03.GLMORS
```

I've had no problem rebuilding the query to this point and if i omit these two parts from each of these JOINS I get some data coming back however I can tell it is wrong as I get more rows than i expect.

Any pointers or notes would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much in advance.

---

I have made an edit to the FROM Clause to be more specific with the parameters:

```
FROM 
    GLDBFA.GLPCT PCT
    INNER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPDA PDA ON  PCT.CTCO=PDA.DACO  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPBX PBX ON  CTCO=PBX.BXCO  AND CTPAGE=PBX.BXPAGE  AND PDA.DAYEAR=PBX.BXYEAR AND PGL.GLMORS=PBX.BXMORS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPGL PGL ON  CTCO=PGL.GLCO  AND CTPAGE=PGL.GLPAGE  AND PDA.DAYEAR=PGL.GLYEAR AND PGL.GLMORS=PBX.BXMORS
```

The underlined error is in the first Left Outer Join:

```
AND PGL.GLMORS=PBX.BXMORS
```

It doesn't like the 'PGL.GLMORS' portion of the statement, but it is fine with it in the second Left Outer Join, this is what makes no sense to me.
Hopefully this helps.

---

I found the error of my ways.
The '&GLMORS' values were actually variables being passed in to Showcase, so I had to code in these variables values to satisfy the FROM.

Thanks again to all for your input and assistance.

Comment: So this is SQL that is being sent to a Sql Server database is it? Or is Showcase a database itself?

Comment: So showcase is a program that connects to our Financial System, but the queries that people build for it seem to break frequently.  I have begun building a Datawarehouse for reporting, and I have recently setup an ODBC connection to our Financial System to pull that data over so that I can re-write these queries in SQL Server.  Since these queries are system generated they seem to use some methods i'm not familiar with - like the bitwise AND in the FROM clause.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Ok - so the financial system is not sqlsvr then.

Comment: No the data sits on an AS400, I believe it is a DB2 Database.

Comment: Suggest you add DB2 tag and alter the headline to ask how to convert a DB2 query with bitwise ops to T-SQL; not my area of expertise sorry

Comment: Awesome thanks I'll do that.  Good call, I never even thought to consider the DB2 side.

Comment: You might want to mention what you mean by "queries breaking". If there is a specific error code or message, please post that. There are no "bitwise AND" operations in DB2 SQL, not the way you suggest anyway. I suspect `&GLMORS` references a parameter name passed from Showcase.

Answer (score 0):

A table structure and/or error message would greatly help.

At a first glance, `&GLMORS=T03.GLMORS` gives me the feeling that you have conflicting `GLMORS` columns, and that you would need something like `&T01.GLMORS=T03.GLMORS`.

Otherwise, a bitwise (&) operator is a binary operator, it takes 2 values and output a result. So you get something liek `5&12=4`. In this case, you have an "unary" `&`, which I have no clues what it should be doing, but it doesn't look like a bitwise AND.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  The error i get is: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 129
The multi-part identifier "PGL.GLMORS" could not be bound.  But it doesn't make sense to me as I have updated the clause (see above) for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the correlation name `PGL` before it is introduced, see comments in the code fragment:

```
INNER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPDA PDA ON  PCT.CTCO=PDA.DACO  
LEFT OUTER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPBX PBX 
   ON  CTCO=PBX.BXCO  
   AND CTPAGE=PBX.BXPAGE  
   AND PDA.DAYEAR=PBX.BXYEAR 
   AND PGL.GLMORS=PBX.BXMORS -- <<< "PGL" is unknown at this point
                             -- it is only introduced on the next line
                             -- and this condition is redundant anyway
                             -- so it can be safely removed
LEFT OUTER JOIN GLDBFA.GLPGL PGL 
   ON  CTCO=PGL.GLCO  
   AND CTPAGE=PGL.GLPAGE  
   AND PDA.DAYEAR=PGL.GLYEAR 
   AND PGL.GLMORS=PBX.BXMORS
```